# Find the time to move up when the escalator is standstill given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Mr. X takes 30 seconds to go up by using "moving up" escalator and takes 120 seconds to come down using "moving up" escalator. Find the time to move up when the escalator is standstill.

MyApproach:

My Confusion is this Can I take the speed of the man and esclator to be x and y?

Because they are acting on the same body so
I applied relative velocity concept

I was doing t= D/(x+y)=$30$

Similarly, another equation would be t= D/(x-y)=$120$

> Am i right in my approach?Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score -1):

$\dfrac{x+y}{D} = \dfrac{1}{30}$, and $\dfrac{x-y}{D} = \dfrac{1}{120}$.

So what is $\dfrac{x}{D}$?

Comment: Speed /Distance.My question is different.You havent understood?

Comment: @Jack: If you know speed/distance, then you also know distance/speed.

Comment: Please read the question what I am trying to say I am not talking about all that.I reiterate to you that I am talking about the concept of relative velocity?Please read the question for more info.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, your equations are fine. Realistically, the man's relative speed would probably be greater going down than up, but I don't think that the question wants you to take this factor into account.

Comment: I am not asking for equations Sir .I am asking How relative velocity concept came into factor because they are the same bodies.Relative velocity is  applied to 2 bodies.